# How's can I determine if a user's clock is displaying 24 hour time?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am writing a WPF "time picker" user control and I want to show/hide parts of the UI based on the user's time format.  What Would be the best way to go about this?

Comment: when you say "user's time format" , do you mean what he has set up his taskbar to display ?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's an easy way. You can take a look at `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat`, you can find what format string is being used for time.